# How can I navigate between Movieclips?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've created a small application, and I got my AS files:

- GameScene.as
- Menu.as
- Game.as

All of them extends Movieclip, and GameScene is the one I load with the application. In GameScene I have defined and added Menu and Game, and by default Game is not visible.
In GameScene I have defined functions to switch to Menu or Game (make either one visible/notvisible). I thought that since GameScene is the parent they could call parent, cast it to GameScene and access the method to swtich visibillity:

(parent as GameScene).SwitchToGame();

But this throws errors saying parent is null? Maybe I should do this by events, but I need to do it quick and dirty for a school project. Calling parent function that owns both Menu and Game to control the visibility should suffice? I'm using Adobe Flash builder.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can cast parent to the GameScene: `GameScene(this.parent).switchToGame()`. An error means that you didn't add Menu or Game to the display list.

```
addChild(menu);
addChild(game);
```

Also, if you operate with Classes, you can pass GameScene to the constructors of Menu, Game, so you will have more flexibility with display list, and don't be forced to stay with parent as GameScene.

Comment: I must be forgetting something, because i get errors, and when I try to print this.parent it is 'null'

Comment: If `this.parent` is null, you didn't add Display Object to the display list. You can debug this process. Create event listener for the event `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded)` and put some trace in handler `onAdded`.

Comment: But by adding Menu or Game to the display list you mean "addChild(menu)" to the GameScene class that is hooked up to the project?

Comment: Yes, you missed something, and some components try to invoke their parent, before they are added to it...